# Question: Prove $\cot (A+ 45^{\circ}) = \frac{\csc(A)-\sec(A)}{\csc(A)+ \sec(A)}$

Tags: trigonometry

> > Question: Prove $\cot (A+ 45^{\circ}) = \dfrac{\csc(A)-\sec(A)}{\csc(A)+\sec(A)}$

My attempt:LHS

$$ \cot (A+ 45^{\circ})$$

$$ \frac{\cos(A+ 45^{\circ})}{\sin(A+45^{\circ})} $$

$$ \cos(45^{\circ}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2},\sin(45^{\circ}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}  $$

$$ \frac{\cos(A+ 45^{\circ})}{\sin(A+45^{\circ})} $$

$$ \frac{\cos(A)\cos(45^{\circ}) - \sin(A)\sin(45^{\circ})}{\sin(A)\cos(45^{\circ}) + \cos(A)\sin(45^{\circ})} $$

$$ \frac{ \frac{\cos(A)}{\sqrt2} - \frac{\sin(A)}{\sqrt2}} { \frac{\sin(A)}{\sqrt2} + \frac{\cos(A)}{\sqrt2}}$$

$$ \frac{\cos(A)-\sin(A)}{\sqrt2} \times \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sin(A)+\cos(A)}  $$

$$ \frac{\cos(A)-\sin(A)}{\sin(A)+\cos(A)}   $$

Now I am stuck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there.  Divide the numerator and denominator of 
$$\frac{\cos(A) - \sin(A)}{\sin(A) + \cos(A)}$$
by $\sin(A)\cos(A)$, then simplify.

Comment: I always get confused by the saying "Divide numerator and denominator" by "so and so" could you explain it to me?

Comment: What I meant is $$\frac{\cos(A) - \sin(A)}{\sin(A) + \cos(A)} \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{\sin(A)\cos(A)}}{\frac{1}{\sin(A)\cos(A)}}$$

Comment: We're you able to complete the proof?

Comment: Yes I was , thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Start working with the right side. Convert all trig functions to sin and cos, cross multiply the numerator and denominator.